# Is there a universal conservation of information theory?

Tags: black-holes, conservation-laws, space-expansion, information

Specifically, is there a working theory from a perspective that relates cosmic expansion (recession?), the increasing total potential information density of the Universe (based on the simplified idea that the physical limit on representing information is $l_p^2$ (planck area???)), and black holes acting as information sinks, i.e. a conservation-of-information balancing feature?
Disclaimer: I'm not a physicist nor do I play one on TV.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by information? From the local observer point of view the universe is quickly emptying out, so there is less and less information available about it. Is information conserved if all observers are agreeing that there is less and less information available?

Comment: More on [conservation of information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conservation-laws+information).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write a comment yet (not enough reputation), so apologies that I have to post this as an answer.

But there are some recent papers, such as [Vopson, The mass-energy-information principle of equivalence](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5123794), putting forth the concept of information mass, or more precisely equivalence between mass and information and energy. So if mass/energy is conserved you could say then information is conserved. The author does write though that one of his assumptions is a non-relativistic classical framework, even though he does mention dark matter.